# NoSQL Workbench support for Local Secondary Indexes in Dynamodb

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, workbench

Is there a way to add a **local secondary index** to a new Dynamodb table definition in NoSQL Workbench (v3.3.0 on macos)?

I am able to configure **global secondary indexes** but nothing for local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. In general using LSIs are discouraged because they limit scalability, with their only benefit being they provide strong consistency on the index.